# Import of .CSV then export to Access 2007 DB via SSIS causes huge bloat

Tags: ssis, ms-access-2007

I've got a 90MB .csv extract I need to push into an Access 2007 DB.

AS A TEST - If I do a straight import of the file with default settings into a new table I end up with a DB of 134MB.

WHAT I NEED TO DO - The .csv extract contains a couple of columns I need to process before pushing them to into the Access DB. To accomplish this I am using SSIS (from SQL Server 2008 install) and using a couple of derived columns to contain the processed columns which then all get pushed into an existing Access table (which has no rows at the start of the process) via an ADO.NET Connection using the following connection string "Data Source=C:\Import\InTheGarden.accdb;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;". (Connection String from Connection in Connection Manager in SSIS)

When I process the data using SSIS I end up with a file of 1.16GB which when compacted comes down to a size of approximately 180MB!!!

Two things: -

- Firstly I don't understand what is causing the bloat and how I might get around to it. I've read I don't know how many articles today on "Access 2007 Bloat" and can't seem to find anything that exlpains what exactly is going on:(
- Secondly, whilst I can import the .csv file above I have another text file of 154MB which needs importing and given that the smaller file caused the DB to bloat to 1.16GB on import I'm not holding out much hope of success with this bigger file not exceeding the 2GB limit!

I would normally use SQL Server as a back end but there are reasons beyond my control as to  why this can't happen:(

Happy to provide further information, Access is not something I use loads so there may be key information which I've missed!! :(

Thx!

Comment: Title should readh "Import of .CSV then export to Access 2007 DB via SSIS causes huge bloat"

Comment: This may be of interest: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q239527/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a staging table in Access to do the import, process the data, and then insert to the real table? You'd use a separate temp database for that so as to avoid the bloat of importing twice. I've done dozens of imports into Access and this has always been the way I do it when I need to process the data before the final append.

Comment: Hi David thx for the response, had started going down that road this morning but with table in the same DB (i.e. no SSIS, just Access imports) just to get me going. Have now moved that "staging" table into a seperate DB and linked to the original DB. Interested in the exact mechanics of how I should manage that staging DB, would be grateful for any insight? Thx!

Comment: It's a temp database. It's disposable. Assuming you're doing this repeatedly, you should have an empty template database and copy that for use with the import. Otherwise, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the CSV into several smaller files and running Access' Compact Database command after importing each one.